# Update base template and apply to all sites who reference it - MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, templates, sharepoint-2007, custom-application

More SharePoint questions from me again today! I thank everyone that has helped thus far!

Here is my situation:

I have to create a custom application inside of sharepoint. I am using a document library which hosts web part pages and i am using Web User Controls to do all the manipluating and displaying of data. Once I build the app the way i want, I am going to turn the doc lib into a template that way i can create the same thing on multiple sites (many customers using this app).

The issue that I am running into is that I need to know what happens/how do I update it so that my changes will apply itself to all sites that are referencing the template.

HELP! anyone who knows how to do this OR has a better idea for creating custom apps that multiple sites will be able to take advantage of would be SO helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer is that you cannot accomplish this, even with a custom site/list definition.**

Once a site or list is created from a site or list definition, it is basically on its own (layouts and master pages modifications, however, do get applied to all sites referencing them).

Once workaround would be to create a site feature that iterates through sites and performs whatever custom action you wish to do.

Comment: I agree, but the changes you would be perform is add / remove of Field then with List Definition you can it. It will be reflected in all the site list template is used. After an IISRESET

Answer (score 0):

For requirement like this, you really should create custom list/site definition. NOT just save customized list into template.
Anything you have updated in list/site definition will be reflect to the sites that are referencing the definitions. Unfortunately this is not the case for Template. You will have to delete the old list you have on other sites, then re-create them again with new template.

how to create list definition - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023.aspx
for site definition please go - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287930.aspx

James